# Passing arguments to executable when debugging with Delve

Tags: go, delve

I would like to pass arguments to the binary file when executing it with `dlv`

```
dlv --listen=:5432 exec /mypath/binary --config=config.toml
```

But when I am doing it I get following error:

```
Error: unknown flag: --config
```

How can I pass arguments to binary when using dlv debugger?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add `--` to tell `dlv` that all subsequent arguments should be passed verbatim to the binary, without trying to parse them:

```
dlv --listen=:5432 exec /mypath/binary -- --config=config.toml
```

See [Delve - Getting Started](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/cli/getting_started.md#debugging-main-packages).